# Seeking a good solution for mitigating the effects of high in-rush current caused by an AC-DC converter

Tags: mains, ac-dc, inrush-current

Many AC-DC power supplies (say, 220VAC to 24VDC) have huge inrush current values.  For example, a device might have an inrush current of 80A@230VAC. This raises the question of how to handle the connection to the AC supply at the electrical panel.

Seems to me that the options are:

1. Connect the unit via a disconnect switch only, without using a circuit breaker. After all, circuit breaker functions (e.g., overload, short circuit etc.) are already baked into the unit itself, and the inrush current is insignificant for the root circuit breaker anyway.
2. Connecting the unit via a high-rated circuit breaker. For example, for a supply with 80A inrush current, I would use a C-curve 16A breaker (whereas, if inrush wasn't an issue, I'd use C-curve 6A or less).
3. Connecting the unit via a lower-rated circuit breaker coupled with an inrush current limiter. This eliminates inrush current and lets me use a lower-rated circuit breaker. However, an inrush current limiter costs money, takes up space in the panel, and adds another point of failure.
4. Some other variation?

Comment: AC to DC transformers do not exist. Do you mean AC to DC power supplies such as in computers, or AC transformers like toroids, or what kind of transformers or power supplies specifically? For example a 1000W computer supply might have a rated inrush current of 90A and household breakers of 10A to 16A are anyway used with them without issues, so at least do not remove any circuit breakers.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that by "transformer", you are referring to a switch mode AC-DC converter.  It depends on the specific device you are using. In the case of a consumer grade product like a computer's PSU then there should be no additional components necessary.

If you using a part that is designed to be integrated into a system, then an external protective device is usually required, generally a slow-blow fuse but your part's datasheet should specify.  The key part is the short duration of the inrush which shouldn't cause the protective device to trip. Not using a protective device which is what it sounds like you *may* be getting at in your first bullet point is unsafe unless the datasheet says otherwise.  Using a circuit breaker with an unnecessarily high trip point is similarly unsafe.